# How to install VMWare ESXi CLI on CentOS 6.0?

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, 64-bit, installation

I'm trying to install VMware-vSphere-CLI-5.0.0-422456.x86_64 onto CentOS 6.0 64bit, but the installer complains:

```
CPAN not able to install following Perl modules on the system. These must be 
installed manually for use by vSphere CLI:

UUID 0.03 or newer
```

I tried to do

```
sudo yum install uuid-perl
```

and also

```
sudo yum install perl-SOAP-Lite perl-Data-Dump perl-Class-MethodMaker perl-Crypt-SSLeay perl-libxml-perl perl-XML-LibXML-Common
```

but this doesn't help.

What else can I try to do?

Comment: Not tempted to just use the vMA?

Comment: @Chopper3: mmm... Can it be used from non-VMWare host and without human interaction? Then I definetely need to try this out.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have uuid, libuuid, and libuuid-devel installed from the yum repo. **libuuid-devel** was the key for me. (I was doing this on CentOS 6.4)

That should be enough for the vmware-install.pl script to do its thing, but you could also run: **`perl -MCPAN -e'install UUID'`** before you try the script again.

Comment: This resolved my issue on CentOS 6.4 with the uuid packages already installed.

Comment: I also missed **Env** and **Fatal** per packages

Answer (score 1):

Like it says, you need to manually install it, because yum provides an old package. Head over to cpan and grab the latest (serving from failed memory I think it was http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Data-UUID-1.217/UUID.pm). Download, extract, change to the folder and run `perl Makefile.pl` and follow the instructions.

Comment: cpan provides its own package management system, controlled by the "cpan" command, so there are quicker ways to install than doing it manually with all dependencies - unless your distro chose to explicitly rip it out. Comes at the price of having to manage two package managers though :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got CentOS 6.2, and downloaded the `Data::UUID` as recommended in Tim's answer.

It seems `Data::UUID` and `UUID` are not the same. I found an unauthorized release of `UUID 0.03` [here](http://search.cpan.org/~cfaber/UUID-0.03/); then, while trying to build it, I found out that the `uuid-devel` and `libuuid-devel` packages are not the same, and `libuuid-devel` is what's needed to build `UUID 0.03`. After that I found [this](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1885147), which seems to indicate that there's no need to build `UUID 0.03`; but after building and installing it, I was able to install the vSphere CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Vsphere cli (even the latest version 5.1.) is not supported for rhel/centos newer than 5.5. Besides, getting all those perl dependencies installed is a nightmare anyway. IMHO, only run CLI on a windows system. Or better yet (if you're going to use windows anyway), forget about cli and just install power-cli for powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was also missing the gcc package.

```
yum install gcc
```

After that I ran again the commands

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
```

and then I was able to install the vsphere cli

```
./vmware-install.pl
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to install vCli from scratch (tested with CentOS 6.3) :

```
yum install perl-Archive-Zip perl-Class-MethodMaker perl-SOAP-Lite perl-libxml-perl perl-XML-SAX perl-Archive-Zip  perl-Class-MethodMaker perl-SOAP-Lite
```

Then I needed EPEL repository to install perl-Data-Dump with yum :

```
 yum install perl-Data-Dump
```

I tried perl-Data-UUID but it didn't work.
So I did as jeremiahRo did :

```
yum install libuuid libuuid-devel
```

and then `perl -MCPAN -e'install UUID` worked with warnings.

`./vmware-install.pl` worked but some errors appeared :

> The following Perl modules were found on the system but may be too old
>   to work  with vSphere CLI:
>
> Compress::Zlib 2.037 or newer  Compress::Raw::Zlib 2.037 or newer 
>   version 0.78 or newer  IO::Compress::Base 2.037 or newer 
>   IO::Compress::Zlib::Constants 2.037 or newer  LWP::Protocol::https
>   5.805 or newer

vCli seems to work now. I just ignored this messages.

PS : Sorry for my english...